Why my top down controller cannot detect the above and right surface?
I am making a top down controller to serve for my rpg but the player can still move through the block  by approach using the top and the right of the player.
source:
from ursina import *
from ursina import physics
class top_down_controller(Entity):
    def __init__(self, model, color, scale = 1, texture = None, collider = 'box', ignore=[]):
        super().__init__(
            model = model,
            color = color,
            scale = scale,
            texture = texture,
            collider = collider,
            ignore = ignore
            )
    def update(self):
        self.x += held_keys['a'] * -0.05
        self.x += held_keys["d"] *0.05
        self.y += held_keys['w'] * 0.05
        self.y += held_keys['s'] * -0.05
        above = raycast(self.world_position, self.up, 0.51, ignore=self.ignore)
        above_left = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(-0.5,0,0), self.up, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        above_right = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0.5,0,0), self.up, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        below = raycast(self.world_position, self.down, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        below_left = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(-0.5,0,0), self.down, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        below_right = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0.5,0,0), self.down, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        left = raycast(self.world_position, self.left, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        left_above = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,0.5,0), self.left, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        left_down = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,-0.5,0), self.left, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        right = raycast(self.world_position, self.right, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        right_above = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,0.5,0), self.right, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        right_down = raycast(self.world_position+Vec3(0,-0.5,0), self.right, 0.51, ignore = self.ignore)
        if any((above.hit, above_left.hit, above_right.hit)) and held_keys['w']:
            self.y = max((r.world_point.y for r in (above, above_left, above_right) if r.hit)) - 0.51
        if any((left.hit, left_above.hit, left_down.hit)) and held_keys['a']:
            self.x = max((r.world_point.x for r in (left, left_above, left_down) if r.hit)) + 0.51
        if any((right.hit, right_above.hit, right_down.hit)) and held_keys['d']:
            self.x = max((r.world_point.x for r in (right_down, right_above, right) if r.hit)) - 0.51
        if any((below_right.hit, below.hit, below_left.hit)) and held_keys['s']:
            self.y = max((r.world_point.y for r in (below, below_left, below_right) if r.hit)) + 0.51 
app  = Ursina()
e = top_down_controller(model = 'quad', color = color.blue)
e1 = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.green, collider = 'box')
app.run()

I tried to add the held_keys to detect if the player want to move left or right or up or down because before i added that the player will teleport to another corner when i pressed the key.Now even worse that the player didnt even follow the rule that cannot go through blocks.

If left is max, then surely right needs to be min (or vice versa).  Right?

it actually worked but i set the length of all rays are the same. Why there is must a min and max?
